# What is the meaning of "Like a Lobster" in the following chapter of "The invisible man"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, books

http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/120/the-invisible-man/2071/chapter-2/

> "Good-afternoon," said the stranger, regarding him, as Mr. Henfrey
>   says, with a vivid sense of the dark spectacles, "like a lobster."

Comment: "like a lobster's protruding eyes"

Comment: The two quotes appear to be continuous, adding to the confusion. It would be clearer if written as _the dark spectacles like a lobster._

Comment: @YosefBaskin the spectacles aren't the 'lobsterish' bit - it's the way he's looking at him.  The spectacles are just thrown in there for a bit of H.G. Wells randomness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's in two parts.**

> "Good afternoon," said the stranger

and:

> regarding him, as Mr. Henfrey says, with a vivid sense of the dark spectacles, "like a lobster."

Lobsters have eyes that stick out, and he was regarding him 'like a lobster', which is basically 'very intently'.

The reason its in speech marks is because it is an expression of Mr. Henfrey.